# How to include leaflet-pip in ionic. Manually, bower or with browserify?

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, bower, browserify, mapbox

Right now in my ionic project I added manually the [`leaflet-pip.min.js`](https://unpkg.com/leaflet-pip@1.0.0/leaflet-pip.min.js)  file in `www/lib/leaflet-pip/`

I would like to do it with bower or with browserify. [Documentation says](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip):

```
 npm install leaflet-pip
```

It is installed in `node_modules/leaflet-pip` directory but what else do I have to do, shouldn't those files be copied (automatically) to `www/lib/leaflet-pip` so thus I can add to my `index.html` the path to `leaflet-pip.min.js`